# Duvida com array e funções

Tags: javascript, array

O objetivo do código é fazer com que cada valor dos arrays (x, y, z) tenham um `"$"` antes, então antes era `"exemplo"` e vira `"$exemplo"`.

Eu tentei fazer da seguinte maneira, porém o output sai como `"undefined"`. Se possível dizer onde foi que eu errei e como o código (consertado) funciona eu agradeço muito.

Esse código é um problema que eu posso usar bastante no futuro.

```
function print (value)
{
        // pega o tamanho do array;
        var all = value.length;
        // repete a função de colocar "$" vezes a quantidade de elementos do array
        for (i=0; i >= all; i++)
        {
            var novo = value[i];
            var paran = novo.length;
            // coloca o "$" no termo atual do array
            for (ii = 0; ii>= paran; ii++)
            {
                var uju = novo.substr(0, -paran)+"$"+novo.substr(-paran);
                var name = "";
                //cria uma string para juntar todos os valores do array
                name = name + uju;
            }
        }
// output teste do código
    console.log(name);
}
var x = ["hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu"];
var y = ["this", "is", "awesome"];
var z = ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", ",", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit"];
//print(x);
/*  var lop = "hehe";
var resultado = lop.substr(0, -4)+"$"+lop.substr(-4);
console.log(resultado);   */
print(x);
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o método [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) dos arrays (`Array.prototype.map`)? :-)

Comment: Não entendi como funciona o map  @LuizFelipe .

Comment: Duas coisas, sem entrar em detalhes: 1) você está complicando muito mais que o necessário e 2) seus loops nunca executam porque as condições que colocou nunca são atendidas

Comment: @bfavaretto o `for` repetiria x vezes até que ele se tornasse igual ao `paran` .

Comment: O segundo argumento do for não é a condição para parar, e sim para continuar. Você está fazendo ao contrário. E não precisa de outro for dentro pra colocar um prefixo nós valores. Nem de substr e afins

Comment: @bfavaretto entendi o que você quis dizer, já consertei.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você consegue colocar o cifrão na frente com um único loop, que altera cada um dos valores, transformando-os em `"$"` + valor original:

```js
var x = ["hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu"];
for (let i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    x[i] = '$' + x[i];
}
console.log(x);
```

Como sugerido pelo Luiz Felipe em um comentário, você também pode usar o método `map` das arrays para obter o mesmo resultado. E o map junto com sintaxe moderna (que pode não funcionar em browsers antigos) fica bem sucinto:

```js
var x = ["hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu"];
var y = x.map(el => '$' + el);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: Após você ter me dito que a minha declaração do for estava errada eu consertei e progredi bastante no programa, cheguei praticamente no mesmo resultado que o seu porém de uma maneira mais longa (e muita, rs).


https://pastebin.com/nkxTLspP 
(excedeu o limite de caracteres)
o outro problema agora é que no terceiro array `z` contém "," e a função que eu usei para remover a , do output remove a do `z` também...
@bfavaretto

Comment: O seu segundo loop aí é feito sobre cada caractere de cada string da array, não faz nenhum sentido. Você nem usa o ii dele. E no final da função você converte toda a array para string, o que emenda tudo e também não parece ter motivo. Dica: tente fazer uma coisa por vez, separadamente.

Answer (score -1):

Outra alternativa é usar o forEach em vez do .map() assim

```
var x = ["hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu"];
x.forEach(  (elemento, indice) => 
          { x[indice] = "$"+elemento } 
         )
```

a vantagem de usar o forEach é que não precisa criar um novo array

**.map ->** quando você quer processar um array e gerar outro com o mesmo número de elementos

**.find ->** quando você quer saber se alguma coisa está dentro do array, ou retornar um elemento só

**.filter ->** quando você quer criar um array com menos elementos do que o original

**.forEach ->** quando você quer processar cada elemento do array, modificando-os ou não.

**.reduce ->** quando você quer calcular alguma coisa usando os elementos do array e retornando um valor só ou um objeto só